# Error when using scipy.misc.imread : AttributeError: __float__

Tags: python, scipy

I am using scipy.misc.imread to convert png files into an array of floats using:

```
scipy.misc.imread(rawImagePath).astype(scipy.float_)
```

where rawImagePath is the complete path of the file.

This is working perfectly the vast majority of the time. However, sometimes I get the error:

```
...
return scipy.misc.imread(rawImagePath).astype(scipy.float_)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 622, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __float__
```

If I then re-run the function on the same file (i.e. same rawImagePath) then it works fine. I've upgraded to the most recent version of pillow (3.4.2) and scipy (0.18.1). I've had a look inside Image.py and scipy.misc.imread but I can't work out where it would try to get the float attribute of an Image object.

Extra Information:

I am running a thread that regularly checks a folder for new files. when it finds a new file it then calls a function which attempts to read the image as an array using the above scipy.misc.imread(...). Could the issue perhaps be something to do with the new file not being complete?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error doesn't directly come from the reading, but from `astype(scipy.float_)`: `__float__` is the method used when `float(somevariable)` is called. That's why you couldn't find it in `Image.py` and `scipy.misc.imread`.

Comment: It does sound very much like an incomplete read of the file, and/or a failed conversion to a numpy array. I don't know how the files arrive, but you could built in a slight delay before reading, when a new file arrives.

Comment: Alternatively, wrap the imread...astype line in a try-except AttributeError statement, wrap that in a short loop (say, 5 times, perhaps again with a short pause after every attempt), `break` when you succeed, and use the `else` clause of the for-loop to handle the case when the image has failed to be read or converted.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the try break loop and will let you know if this fixes it. The file is being written to a folder by another process. My program then "watches" the folder and when a new file appears it tries to load it as an array. It is possible that it sees the new file appear before it is fully written. 

I still don't think I understand where the error comes from though.What has happened during the imread that makes it sometimes able to get the __float__ attribute and sometimes not? If the file is incomplete/corrupted does the imread not fail with some other error?