# ndimage.imread(image_file).astype(float) not working in PIL

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to read an image file and using scipy ndimage and then trying to convert the corresponding image file as float ndarray. But its throwing exception:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 512, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __float__
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Possibly usefule references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690442/error-when-using-scipy-misc-imread-attributeerror-float and http://stackoverflow.com/a/15345969/2422125