# Error when using scipy.misc.imread inside the loop

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, scikit-image, imread

I have a case similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690442/error-when-using-scipy-misc-imread-attributeerror-float/47432247).

Faced it when training deep learning model and reading images inside the loop.

```
scipy.misc.imread(rawImagePath).astype(numpy.float32)
```

The code above is working perfectly the vast majority of the time, but sometimes I get the error:

```
batch 90, loading batch data...
x path: /path_to_dataset/train/9.png
2017-10-31 20:23:34.531221: W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:294] _0_input_producer: Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt with queue not closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 452, in <module>
    batch_X = load_data(batch_X_paths)
  File "/path_to_my_script/utilities.py", line 85, in load_data
    x = misc.imread(batch_X_paths[i]).astype(np.float32)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

The difference is: I have a fixed set of files and I do not write new ones to the directory.

I made a little research and figured out that error comes not from

```
numpy.astype()
```

but from

```
PIL.Image.open()
```

***scipy.misc*** uses ***PIL*** under the hood.

Also, I managed to reproduce this bug in *Jupyter Notebook*. I made a loop with *reading/astype* code inside. After few seconds (the size of my test .png is about 10MB) I interrupt cell's execution and voila!

[error reproduced in Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6uOo.png)

Inside ***scipy.misc*** sources there is a code like this:

```
def imread(name, flatten=False, mode=None):
    im = Image.open(name)
    return fromimage(im, flatten=flatten, mode=mode)
```

***Image*** here is a ***PIL*** object. And ***Image.open()*** gives us 0-dimension list when interrupting cell.

I have tried Evert's advice and made a loop with ***try/except***, but sometimes it fails even after 5 attempts.

Also I tried ***OpenCV imread()*** method instead of ***scipy.misc*** and sometimes it fails too. Error text:

```
libpng error: incorrect data check
```

So... I ran out of ideas.

Comment: Maybe, your images’ format is not `standard`.

Comment: When I try to read the same image outside the loop it works fine. And most of the time it works fine inside the loop too. So I don,t think, that it is image format issue.

Comment: Some images' format, not all.

Comment: No. Look. Let's take one particular image. I'm running the loop and trying to read that one image. 100 iterations all goes fine, but sometimes on 101 or 120th or on any other random step it fails. How can it be connected to the format?

Comment: Have you tried putting a small delay, like a few ms, (or even large (a second or so)) delay in the loop to see if that helps? I wonder if it's some weird OS holding onto the original image lock or something...

Comment: I have tried to put several reading operations of different images in one iteration. So we get a natural delay in this case. And no, still errors =(

Comment: Are you randomly reading in images?  It could be that one of your PNGs got damaged.  You can also use skimage's ImageCollection to load the images into a list-like object (it will load images on demand, as the list is accessed).

Comment: Can you provide an example PNG (e.g. `8.png`) so we can try to reproduce this problem? Using an exact copy of your jupyter notebook code does not cause errors for me when loading some random png.